# Stackblitz integration with gitgub

Tags: angular, github, stackblitz

According to [stackblitz docs](https://developer.stackblitz.com/guides/user-guide/importing-projects) I should be able to get a github Angular project into stackblitz with `stackblitz.com/github/{GH_USERNAME}/{REPOSITORY_NAME}` but when I try this I get a 404 page.

I am signed into stackblitz with my github account and the repository is not private.

The github project is a Angular one and has a `package.json` in the root folder.

Has anyone else managed to get this feature working (or is there a better way to get from VSCode locally to stackblitz?)

Comment: Is your repo private ?

Comment: No its not private.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the link?